# powershell script works in run.exe but doesn't work as scheduled task

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I scheduled this task below and when I click run in Task Scheduler it doesn't throw any errors but the script doesn't execute:
Program:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "& S:\Scripts\Download-USPTO-Forms.ps1 -destinationFolder 'S:\Scripts\USPTO Forms'"
```

When I open Run.exe and run this cmd then the Powershell window opens and the script executes:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "& S:\Scripts\Download-USPTO-Forms.ps1 -destinationFolder 'S:\Scripts\USPTO Forms'"
```

Why is that? Any ideas? The task seems to be scheduled correctly.

Comment: Why do you have this in the scheduled task command? `Add arguments:`

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: Oh the newline was removed in my original thread. I meant that in the "Program" box in task scheduler I added: 
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe 
But then in the "Add arguments" part of task scheduler, I added: 
-Command "& S:\Scripts\Download-USPTO-Forms.ps1 -destinationFolder 'S:\Scripts\USPTO Forms'" 
And that's consistent with what you guys just mentioned. So why does this not work then?

Comment: Is the script file on a remote system?  If so, have you specified the proper credentials for the scheduled task to run under?

Comment: Is the 'S:' drive a 'mapped drive'? If so, it may not be available to the script when it runs. Are you running is under your account?

Comment: Thanks Andy and guys! So I had two problems. I didn't need to use the -Command operator AND task scheduler doesn't have access to the mapped drive. So this works now:
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File "C:\Users\flala\Documents\Scripts\Download-USPTO-Forms.ps1" -destinationFolder "C:\Users\flala\Documents\Scripts\USPTO-Forms"

I have access to the mapped drive and the task scheduler runs under my credentials. So why can't it access the mapped drive? How do I get scheduler to access the drive? Do I need to start another thread to resolve that issue? :) Thanks!

Comment: Oh I got it! I used the share name for the mapped drive \\computername\data\ and now it works! Thank you so much! You guys rock!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the call operator?

```
powershell -File "S:\Scripts\Download-USPTO-Forms.ps1" -destinationFolder "S:\Scripts\USPTO Forms"
```

Furthermore, ensure the task has properly mapped drives and permissions.

Comment: Thank you! You're right that was unnecessary. That helped!